# Unknown system variable ‘query_cache_size’ on amazon rds mysql 8

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-8.0

I have been using MySQL connector jar version 5.1.44. I have been trying to connect amazon rds MySQL 8 through JDBC connection from a local machine but I'm getting an Unknown system variable ‘query_cache_size’. Can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to enable query_cache in an RDS MySQL 8 instance.

AWS removed this option in MySQL 8, because it was "so problematic".

Source: [AWS Database Blog - Best practices for configuring parameters for Amazon RDS for MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-1-parameters-related-to-performance/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably is using the wrong version of mysql connector driver.
Update it to version compatible to MySQL 8, you can find the available versions here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java